# Random 'The connection was reset' webpage with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

We use selenium to test whether we are able to browse. But sometimes intermittently, the selenium types the actual URL in the address bar, but the page does not load, and instead "The connection was reset" page loads.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

#Timeout setting block
self.selenium.set_timeout(90)
While True:
   if time.time() - start_time < 90:
     try:
       # Waiting 1 second for page load
       self.selenium.wait_for_page_to_load('1000')
       self.log.info('Page loaded')
     except Exception as e:

       msg = ('Ignore Selenium error till page loads:'
                       ' {0}'.format(e))
       self.log.info(msg)
   else:
     break
```

Comment: "connection reset by peer" is browser error? Selenium doesn't do anything special with proxyfication or similar if you are not defining it explicitly.

Comment: Please copy your code what have you tried.

Comment: Yes, the best way is ti show how are you initializing webdriver and how are you starting a test (just a dummy one).

Comment: You are using to complicated logic for some simple manipulations. Waiting for 1 second if the page is loaded, doing it in a try block and giving a timeout of 90 to it.. Could you please tell what are you going to achieve?

Comment: The total time that the page should wait in my case is 90 secs, but inbetween we check whether the page has actually loaded, say if it gets loaded within 20 secs, we come out of loop. But what happens here is after some 10 secs, "The connection was reset" page loads and since it is not going to reload again, the connection reset page remains, instead of actual webpage

Comment: if i could make a recommendation - you could find a better tool to just check whether your service is available.  a simple "cUrl" would do.  you are wasting a lot of time having selenium do this.